# Git Push to Remote without Pull and Prevent Remote Files from Being Removed

Tags: git, push, pull

I have several local Git repositories on different nodes. All of them are pushing their own files to the same branch on the same remote and these files are totally different from one node to another. No node need to have access to files from other nodes. To save bandwidth, I don't want to do `git pull` on the nodes before they push their files. Is there any way `git push --force` can push the files from nodes to a single branch on the remote without deleting the files committed by other nodes?

Comment: No, there is no such magic. Either you override commits with forced push, or separate files in different branches (one branch for node should be enough), or collect all files in one branch using `git pull`.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Assign each node a private name that is reserved to *that node*.  I'll give an example of how this can be made to work with human actors below.  You'll have to come up with your own system for machine actors.  You'll then have to come up with your own system for *using* the resulting commits—it's not as simple as just picking a commit; you'll need a real deployment engine.

## Long

The short answer is both no and yes, or perhaps [mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)).  The basic issue here is that `git push` doesn't push *files;* `git push` sends *commits*.  These commits are identified by their unique hash IDs.  For instance, if  want to send you the commit `a123456` I can run:

```
git push <string-that-leads-my-Git-to-your-Git> a123456:<some-name>
```

Remember that each commit lists its own *parent commit* hash ID(s), which becomes important in just a moment.  This `a123456` must have some parent—some other hash ID.  But right now let's just look at this particular `git push` command.

When I choose to run this `git push` command, the thing I must put on the left hand side of the colon, in this `git push` command, is a specifier for the *commit hash ID* of the commit I want to send to you.  (In this case I've chosen an abbreviated hash ID that I just made up.)  The thing I must put on the right hand side of the colon, in this same command, is the *name* that I want to ask your Git to use to *save* this commit.

We'll come back to this in a moment; right now we need to look at how Git commits work.

#### How commits work

The way Git really works is remarkably simple.  Every commit has its own, unique hash ID.  You have seen these hash IDs because `git log` shows them.  But they're big and ugly and nobody can remember them.  That's why we have Git remember them for us.  *All* of the hash IDs *except for the very last one*—the most recent, or *tip* commit, of a branch—are remembered *in* some *other* commit.

We might start out, for instance, with a tiny repository with just three commits:

```
A <-B <-C
```

Instead of writing out their actual, apparently-random, hash IDs, we can use single uppercase letters to draw how Git works.  Commit `C` is the *latest* commit, so it has, inside it, the actual hash ID of commit `B` (whatever that may be).  So we say that commit `C` *points to* commit `B`.

Meanwhile, commit `B` contains the actual hash ID of commit `A`: `B` points to `A`.  `A` is a special case: it's the very first commit; it *can't* point to the previous commit as there was no previous commit when we made `A`.  So `A` points nowhere, and this lets Git stop.

#### How branch names work

Somehow, though, we must *find* commit `C`.  Git can only *find* commits—at least directly—by their hash IDs.  So we must save the hash ID of commit `C` somewhere.  We could write it down on a scrap of paper or a whiteboard, and type it in, but that's pretty terrible.  Instead, Git lets us store the hash ID in a *name*.

The names you can use here come in many forms but the one we use most often is a *branch* name.  Branch names have one special property: we can use `git checkout branch` to get *on* that branch.  When we do, Git attaches the special name `HEAD` *to* that branch-name.  The branch name itself just contains the raw hash ID of the actual commit—in this case, of commit C—so that branch name *points to* the commit, just as each commit points back to its parent:

```
A <-B <-C   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Now let's say we want to make a new branch `dev`.  We'll create it, pointing to commit `C`—two names for one commit; that's quite OK and it just means that all three commits are now on *both* branches.  We'll have Git attach `HEAD` to `dev`, too:

```
A--B--C   <-- dev (HEAD), master
```

Now we'll make a *new* commit.  Because we have `C` checked out, the new commit's *parent* will be `C`.  Git will *create* the new commit from whatever source code we decide we should snapshot (which we have to copy into Git's *index* using `git add`) and with whatever metadata we've told Git to use and whatever it has figured out on its own (our name, email address, log message, the current time, and the hash ID of commit `C`):

```
A--B--C
       \
        D
```

Note how `D` points back to `C`, through the parent commit hash ID in the metadata.

All of the data and metadata goes into the cryptographic hashing algorithm, so that the act of *writing out* commit `D` produces the new hash ID *for* the new commit `D`.  Now comes the magic step: Git simply *overwrites* the branch name—the one to which `HEAD` is attached—with the new hash ID, so that the current branch name points to the new commit:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

The other names have not changed.  The *current* branch name, `dev`, now points to the new commit, so that `dev` remembers hash `D`.  `HEAD` has not changed either—it's still attached to `dev`.

#### How `git push` works

When I have my Git call up your Git, I've told my Git:

- which commit I want to send, and
- what name I want my Git to ask your Git to use, to remember that commit.

My Git asks your Git: *Hey, do you have commit `a123456`?*  (Let's say `a123456` is my commit `D` in that simple four-commit repository above.)  Since I just *made* it, you don't have it.  So then my Git asks your Git if you have `C`, because my Git has to send all the commits that *lead up to* `D`, not just `D` itself.  You either do have `C` or you don't.  If you don't, my Git asks about `B` too, and so on.  But you probably already have `C`.  Probably, *your* `master` points to the shared commit `C`.

So my Git packages up just commit `D`, and sends that.  Then my Git asks your Git to set *one of your branch names*.

If I've chosen to ask your Git to set your `dev`, and you don't *have* a `dev`, your Git will *create* your `dev`, and now *you* have the same thing I do.

Meanwhile, suppose Ernie had the same `A-B-C` commits in Ernie's Git, but Ernie made a new `dev` and a new commit `E`.  Ernie now has:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        E   <-- dev
```

Ernie does not have `D` because Ernie's Git hasn't talked to my Git, nor vice versa.  Just after I've sent you my `D` and asking you to create *your* `dev`, Ernie has *his* Git send you *his* `E` and asks you to set your `dev` to point to commit `E`.

Your Git now has:

```
        E   <-- polite request to set your `dev` here
       /
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- dev
```

**If** your Git obeys the polite request, your Git will move your `dev` to point to `E`, and hence *forget how to find `D`*.  So your Git just says *No, I can't do that.*

If Ernie changes his `git push` to use `--force`, Ernie changes his polite request to a command: *Set `dev` to point to `E` and I really mean it!*  Your Git can still reject that command, but by default your git will obey the command, and lose `D`.  And that's what you're seeing when you try to use this technique.

Note that regardless of *how* I run `git push`, my Git is going to ask your Git to set some name.  The method I showed above—where I choose a hash ID on the left of a colon and a name on the right—is not how we usually spell `git push`.  We usually write:

```
git push origin dev
```

But what this *means* is `git push origin dev:dev`.  The thing on the left, `dev`, is my name for my commit `D`.  The thing on the right, `dev`, is just the actual name `dev`.  Git just lets us express this without the colon in between.

#### It's the name clash that's the problem, so avoid the name clash

Regardless of how however *sends* commits to your central collection point chooses to name *their* branches, what you need to have happen *at* the central collection point is simple.  In the above, we had two actors: there was me, under the name `dev`, sending my commit `D`, and Ernie, under the name `dev`, sending his commit `E`.  This fails because my `D` and his `E` both lead back to the shared `C`, but we're trying to use *one* name to remember two incompatible commits.

But what if you give me a private name to use?  For simplicity, suppose my name is Dave (it isn't) and you have me push my `dev` to `incoming/dave` rather than just `dev`.  I'll run:

```
git push origin dev:incoming/dave
```

Meanwhile you will have Ernie run:

```
git push origin dev:incoming/ernie
```

Now in *your* Git repository, you will have this:

```
        E   <-- incoming/ernie
       /
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- incoming/dave
```

Suppose now I make a new commit `F` and Ernie makes a new commit `G`, with each of us working on our `dev`.  Remember, commit hash IDs are universal, so my `F` and Ernie's `G` are by definition different big ugly hash IDs.  Ernie will push his `G` with parent `E`.  He'll have his Git find `G` by *his* name `dev` but ask you to set *your* name `incoming/ernie`.  You will end up with this:

```
        E--G   <-- incoming/ernie
       /
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- incoming/dave
```

Your `incoming/ernie` can be updated safely because `G` leads back to `E`, just as it must.

I haven't sent my `F` yet, but when I do, this `F` will point back to `D` and I'll have you update your `incoming/dave`.  That will be OK because `incoming/dave` will point to `F` which leads back to `D`: no commits will be lost.

Obviously, someone—*you*—will have to do something to *integrate* these separate lines of development.  But that's not Dave and Ernie's problem, that's yours.